# Next.js form works locally but not on live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have been implementing a Next.js app for a side project of mine. It is a basic brochure-style site with a contact form.

The form works perfectly fine when the site is run locally, however I have just published the site to Netlify and now when submitting a form I encounter the following error:

```
POST https://dux.io/api/form 404
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at e.exports (contact.js:9)
at e.exports (contact.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.d.(/contact/anonymous function) (https://dux.io/_next/static/cFeeqtpSGmy3dLZAZZWRt/pages/contact.js:9:4271)
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

This is my Form Submit function:

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const { name, email, option, message } = this.state;

const form = await axios.post('/api/form', {
  name,
  email,
  option,
  message
});

this.setState(initialState);}
```

This is my server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mailer = require('./mailer');
const compression = require('compression');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(compression());
  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
    const { email = '', name = '', option = '', message = '' } = req.body;
    mailer({ email, name, option, text: message })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('success');
        res.send('success');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('failed', error);
        res.send('badddd');
      });
  });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Read on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like nextjs tries to render the `/api/form` page and you get a not found with that.

Please make sure you start the server with `node server.js` instead of `next start`.

Comment: I am currently doing that! The following are my scripts from my package.json file:
`"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "export": "npm run build && next export"
}`

Any other ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: You can't use custom next.js server, because Netlify can serve static pages only.

Answer (score 0):

What about try to use full endpoint `http://~~~/api/form` instead of just `/api/form`?

Or I think, you can solve this problem if you use process.env

```
const config = {
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/api'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.endpoint = 'hostname/api'
}
```